# SQL Server Migration Assistant - How to migrate access to SQL Server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-migration, sql-server-migration-assi

I'm trying to migrate our Access Database to a database on SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I try to migrate it, I get an error message:

> You cannot connect to an older version (SQL Server 2008) of target SQL Server from a higher version SSMA project (Project type = SQL Server 2014)

I downloaded and did a 'Typical' installation of 'Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant v5.3 for Access' but when it loads, I get the loading screen for a brief second that says 'Microsoft SQL Server 2014' and then the Migration Assistant loads.

I try and migrate my databases but at the end, I get the above error message.

I have MS Sql Server 2014 Management Studio installed on my computer. Perhaps, the migration assistant is using the native engine to load the Migration Assistant? Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

During the migration, you get a screen where you can specify the Migration name and the path for the Migration Project. In that same window, there is another drop-down where you can specify what you would like to migrate to. The choices are SQL Server 2014, 2012, 2008 and 2005.

I selected 2008 from the drop-down in the 'Migrate To:' field and clicked on Next.

Migration was eventually successfully completed.